# fcrepo-indexing-solr not working as expected with fedora commons. `Credentials may not be null` error while communicating messages

Tags: solr, apache-karaf, fedora-commons

I have installed fcrepo-indexer-solr in karaf. And tried to create new objects in fedora repository. Then I found the following errors in karaf logs.

Also, no errors if I delete any object in the repo. The errors are only when I create or update any objects. What am I missing here? Please suggest.

```
2016-04-04 14:15:47,696 | INFO  | Consumer[fedora] | FcrepoSolrIndexer                | 62 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.2 | Index Routing Error: FcrepoSolrIndexer
2016-04-04 08:42:00,664 | ERROR | Consumer[fedora] | DefaultErrorHandler              | 62 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.2 | Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-eslxarv-test-emea-nsn-net-net-42159-1459729846394-0-7 on ExchangeId: ID-eslxarv-test-emea-nsn-net-net-42159-1459729846394-0-6). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 11 caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Credentials may not be null. Processed by failure processor: FatalFallbackErrorHandler[Channel[Log(FcrepoSolrIndexer)[Index Routing Error: ${routeId}]]]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[FcrepoSolrRouter  ] [FcrepoSolrRouter  ] [activemq://topic:fedora                                                       ] [     10028]
[FcrepoSolrRouter  ] [choice1           ] [when[{header{header(org.fcrepo.jms.eventType)} == http://fedora.info/definitio] [     10029]
[FcrepoSolrRouter  ] [to2               ] [direct:index.solr                                                             ] [     10028]
[FcrepoSolrIndexer ] [removeHeaders1    ] [removeHeaders[CamelHttp*]                                                     ] [         0]
[FcrepoSolrIndexer ] [filter1           ] [filter[{not ((header{header(org.fcrepo.jms.identifier)} startsWith Simple: {{a] [     10029]
[FcrepoSolrIndexer ] [to4               ] [fcrepo:{{fcrepo.baseUrl}}?preferOmit=PreferContainment                        ] [     10026]
[                  ] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]

Exchange
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
        Id                  ID-eslxarv-test-emea-nsn-net-net-42159-1459729846394-0-6
        ExchangePattern     InOnly
        Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID:myservername.net-57410-1459689911951-3:1:1:1:5, CamelRedelivered=true, CamelRedeliveryCounter=10, CamelRedeliveryMaxCounter=10, JMSCorrelationID=null, JMSCorrelationIDAsBytes=null, JMSDeliveryMode=2, JMSDestination=topic://fedora, JMSExpiration=0, JMSMessageID=ID:myservername.net-57410-1459689911951-3:1:1:1:5, JMSPriority=4, JMSRedelivered=false, JMSReplyTo=null, JMSTimestamp=1459730500591, JMSType=null, JMSXGroupID=null, JMSXUserID=null, org.fcrepo.jms.baseURL=http://fedoraserver.net:8080/fedora/rest, org.fcrepo.jms.eventID=d4/68/eb/03/d468eb03-7f4a-4d1e-a843-71f85c01911e, org.fcrepo.jms.eventType=http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/repository#NODE_ADDED,http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/repository#PROPERTY_ADDED, org.fcrepo.jms.identifier=/6c/bf/93/c0/6cbf93c0-c686-41fb-96fd-9ed7257ce0ab/f0/2b/fc/46/f02bfc46-5f36-4fc1-969d-b54a8c8fc087, org.fcrepo.jms.properties=http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/repository#lastModified,http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/repository#primaryType,http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/repository#lastModifiedBy,http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/repository#created,http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/repository#mixinTypes,http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/repository#createdBy,http://fedora.info/definitions/v4/repository#uuid, org.fcrepo.jms.timestamp=1459730500485, org.fcrepo.jms.user=fedoraAdmin, org.fcrepo.jms.userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36}
        BodyType            null
        Body                [Body is null]
]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Credentials may not be null
        at org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull(Args.java:54)[78:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.auth.AuthState.update(AuthState.java:113)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.fcrepo.client.FcrepoHttpClientBuilder$PreemptiveAuthInterceptor.process(FcrepoHttpClientBuilder.java:117)[97:org.fcrepo.client.fcrepo-java-client:0.1.2]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:132)[78:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:182)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.fcrepo.client.FcrepoClient.executeRequest(FcrepoClient.java:268)[97:org.fcrepo.client.fcrepo-java-client:0.1.2]
        at org.fcrepo.client.FcrepoClient.head(FcrepoClient.java:96)[97:org.fcrepo.client.fcrepo-java-client:0.1.2]
        at org.fcrepo.camel.FcrepoProducer.getMetadataUri(FcrepoProducer.java:158)[95:org.fcrepo.camel.fcrepo-camel:4.4.1]
        at org.fcrepo.camel.FcrepoProducer.doRequest(FcrepoProducer.java:141)[95:org.fcrepo.camel.fcrepo-camel:4.4.1]
        at org.fcrepo.camel.FcrepoProducer.process(FcrepoProducer.java:99)[95:org.fcrepo.camel.fcrepo-camel:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor.process(FilterProcessor.java:57)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112)[65:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.2]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:544)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:504)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:474)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_71]
2016-04-04 08:42:00,669 | WARN  | Consumer[fedora] | EndpointMessageListener          | 62 - org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.16.2 | Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Credentials may not be null]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Credentials may not be null
        at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1642)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:195)[65:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:116)[65:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.2]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:544)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:504)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:474)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1103)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1095)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:992)[91:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-jms:3.2.14.RELEASE_1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)[:1.8.0_71]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)[:1.8.0_71]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.8.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Credentials may not be null
        at org.apache.http.util.Args.notNull(Args.java:54)[78:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.auth.AuthState.update(AuthState.java:113)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.fcrepo.client.FcrepoHttpClientBuilder$PreemptiveAuthInterceptor.process(FcrepoHttpClientBuilder.java:117)[97:org.fcrepo.client.fcrepo-java-client:0.1.2]
        at org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:132)[78:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore:4.4.4]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:182)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)[77:org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient:4.5.1]
        at org.fcrepo.client.FcrepoClient.executeRequest(FcrepoClient.java:268)[97:org.fcrepo.client.fcrepo-java-client:0.1.2]
        at org.fcrepo.client.FcrepoClient.head(FcrepoClient.java:96)[97:org.fcrepo.client.fcrepo-java-client:0.1.2]
        at org.fcrepo.camel.FcrepoProducer.getMetadataUri(FcrepoProducer.java:158)[95:org.fcrepo.camel.fcrepo-camel:4.4.1]
        at org.fcrepo.camel.FcrepoProducer.doRequest(FcrepoProducer.java:141)[95:org.fcrepo.camel.fcrepo-camel:4.4.1]
        at org.fcrepo.camel.FcrepoProducer.process(FcrepoProducer.java:99)[95:org.fcrepo.camel.fcrepo-camel:4.4.1]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.FilterProcessor.process(FilterProcessor.java:57)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)[62:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.16.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112)[65:org.apache.camel.camel-jms:2.16.2]
        ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have specified wrong Authentication Hostname. It is fixed after I changed it to null.

The following lines should be set to null in $KARAF_HOME/etc/org.fcrepo.index.solr.cfg

AuthenticationHost =

Answer (score 0):

**Credentials may not be null**

Looks a lot like you are missing the credentials for your application. Make sure you have those set.